# What is the hash-rate difference in the available CPU miners?

Tags: cpu-mining, new-user

From these miners, is there a difference in hash-rate with the same hardware, if so what is it for your hardware?

### CPU Miners

- Wolf's CPUMiner - Open-source
- YAM Miner - Dev fee, Closed-source
- Claymore's CPU Miner - Dev fee, Closed-source

Comment: based on your comment on the answer @justinEU4 provided below it appears as if you are asking at least two different questions (you want the GPU and CPU software compared separately). Please edit your question to be more specific (separating your GPU and CPU questions) and be more precise in the criteria to be used for "pros and cons"

Comment: Edited to focus on CPU since there are more options.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question misunderstands how miners work. Within the ones you listed, they each have a different purpose.

Wolf's CPUMiner, YAM Miner, and Claymore's CPU Miner are all meant for CPU. Some work on more operating systems than others.

Wolf's GPU miner and Claymore's GPU miner are both meant for AMD GPUs. Wolf's is open-source, and Claymore charges a mining fee but is sometimes a little bit faster.

All the ones you mentioned are about the same difficulty to use. The Monero Spelunker is the easiest to use CPU miner for Windows.

Performance for each will vary significantly depending on what cards/chips you have.

For a good start, check out the the [Wiki on /r/MoneroMining](https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/wiki/index). It doesn't have information for all the miners you had listed (yet), but it should help you understanding mining a little bit more.

Comment: You slightly answered my question. "Claymore is sometimes a little bit faster" I know that they are CPU and GPU, I'm going to edit it so others understand that I don't want the CPU and GPU compared to each other. I know what mining is, I just want to know what the difference between the software is. Also, that wiki page is not close to finished.

Comment: Outdated answer.